# How to fix "Data not saved"?

Tags: java

I'm making a new quiz game. I'm trying to solve a saving data problem with score. When I open the activity the score is visible but when the second time I open the same activity I lose the score and all data returns to 0. How can I fix it?

I used SharedPreferences to save Data cause I don't use database servers.

private void Punteggio ( ) {

```
    // TODO: initialization 

    final int score = getIntent ( ).getIntExtra ( Home.DATA_Score , 0 );
    last_score = score;
    last_score_Label.setText ( "Ultimo punteggio: " + last_score );


    // TODO: Miglior punteggio e ultimo punteggio
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences ( "GAME_DATA" , MODE_PRIVATE );
    highscore = settings.getInt ( "HIGHSCORE" , 0 );


    // TODO: Saving highscore
    // Last score isn't saved but highscore is saved
    if ( score > highscore ) {
        highscore_Label.setText ( "Miglior punteggio: " + score );

        // Salvataggio
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit ( );
        editor.putInt ( "HIGHSCORE" , score );
        editor.putInt ( "LAST_SCORE", last_score );
        editor.apply ( );
    } else {
        highscore_Label.setText ( "Miglior punteggio: " + highscore );
    }

}
```

// I want to save graphicAvatar and formaLabel but they're not saved

```
private void showGrafico(){

    final int number = getIntent ().getIntExtra ( Home.DATA_Avatar, 0 );
    number_avatar = number;
    switch (number){
        case 1: graphicAvatar.setImageResource ( R.drawable.negative );
            formaLabel.setText ( "Stato di forma: Pessimo" );
            break;
        case 2: graphicAvatar.setImageResource ( R.drawable.normal );
            formaLabel.setText ( "Stato di forma: Normale" );
            break;
        case 3: graphicAvatar.setImageResource ( R.drawable.positive );
            formaLabel.setText ( "Staot di forma: Ottimo" );
            break;
    }


}
```

// I expect the data is saved but it's not like I expected...

// I modified the code and is like this but the problem is still persisting:
 private void showGrafico(){

```
    final int number = getIntent ().getIntExtra ( Home.DATA_Avatar, 0 );
    switch (number){
        case 1: graphicAvatar.setImageResource ( R.drawable.negative );
            formaLabel.setText ( "Stato di forma: Pessimo" );
            break;
        case 2: graphicAvatar.setImageResource ( R.drawable.normal );
            formaLabel.setText ( "Stato di forma: Normale" );
            break;
        case 3: graphicAvatar.setImageResource ( R.drawable.positive );
            formaLabel.setText ( "Staot di forma: Ottimo" );
            break;
    }

    // TODO: Miglior punteggio e ultimo punteggio

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DATA_AVATAR", MODE_PRIVATE);
    number_avatar = pref.getInt ( "NUMBER" , 0 );

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit ( );
    editor.putInt ( "NUMBER" , number_avatar );
    editor.commit ();


}
```

// and then also:
  private void showPunteggio ( ) {

```
    // TODO: inizializzazione variabili

    final int score = getIntent ( ).getIntExtra ( Home.DATA_Score , 0 );
    last_score = score;
    last_score_Label.setText ( "Ultimo punteggio: " + last_score );




    // TODO: Miglior punteggio e ultimo punteggio
    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("GAME_DATA",0);
    highscore = settings.getInt ( "HIGHSCORE" , 0 );


    // TODO: Salvataggio Miglior Punteggio
    if ( score > highscore ) {
        highscore_Label.setText ( "Miglior punteggio: " + score );

        // Salvataggio
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit ( );
        editor.putInt ( "HIGHSCORE" , score );
        editor.commit ( );
    } else {
        highscore_Label.setText ( "Miglior punteggio: " + highscore );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `apply()` can you try calling `commit()`?

```
editor.commit();
```

Please note that `commit()` is a blocking call and should be avoided in UI thread. In case `commit()` does not work let me know.

By the way, how you are getting SharedPreferences object is not clear. It should be:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("XYZ", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: I tried as you told me but the problem is still persisting

Answer (score 0):

You're not initizaling your SharedPreferences correctly- you should be calling:

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("GAME_DATA",0);
```

[Here's a good SharedPreferences example.](https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial)

Comment: I tried as you told me but the problem is still persisting